# Почему вылезает ошибка ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous

Tags: sql, psql

Процедура:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.mypr(userid integer)
 RETURNS TABLE(id integer, surname varchar)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    begin
        return query (select id,sername from public.mytable where id = userid);
        return;
    end
$function$
;
```

Таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE public.mytable (
    id int4 NOT NULL,
    surname varchar NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

хм. Грабли синтаксического сахара.

```
RETURNS TABLE(id integer, surname varchar)
```

Здесь помимо описания формата результата функции объявлены две переменные: `id` и `surname`. Чтобы можно было делать `return next`

```
id := 1;
surname := 'foo';
return next;
```

А далее идёт запрос:

```
select id,surname from public.mytable where id = userid
```

И парсер языка plpgsql уже не понимает, хотите вы обратиться к переменной id или к полю таблицы.

```
select t.id,t.surname from public.mytable as t where t.id = userid
```